# convert name value pairs to xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath

given a bunch of data in the form of name-value pairs how can i construct that into xml?

eg:

Title : Mr

Name : John

Surname : Doe

as valid xml
sililar to:

```
<Data>
<Title>Mr</Title>
<Name >John</Name >
<Surname >Doe</Surname >
</Data>
```

Comment: You have given an example of the transformation you would like to see. Are you asking how to actually write the code to do that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Biggest pitfall with new xml users is trying to FIGHT xml to look the way you want it to look.  My advice:  as long as it works, however it works, let it work.  Stop trying to get it to "look" how you think it should look.  Its nothing but wasted time.

Comment: @Will: ACK. Most of the time, caring for how serialized XML *looks* implies the profound misunderstanding that XML is text and could be treated with text tools (like regex). Once you make that mistake, you begin to care for how the output XML is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a dictionary with the key value pairs..something like..

```
XElement xe = new XElement("Data", from kvp in dict
                           select new XElement(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using .NET:

1. [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx)
2. [XmlArrayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx), [XmlArrayItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using XElement in System.Linq.Xml

```
var data=nameValuePair.Value;
var xelement=new XElement("Data",
                         new XElement("Title",data.Title),
                         new XElement("Name",data.Name),
                         new XElement("Surname",data.Surname));
```

Does this answer you question?

Comment: Thats a shame, Linq to XML is worth the upgrade to 3.5 all by by itself IMO

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, use an XML-aware API to do it. Don't simply read the string and write out between tags. It's tempting since it's convenient, but you have to worry about character and entity encoding to generate XML properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the all the data is always in the said form & you have a bunch of it,
Create a class with members & serialize it to xml.

```
    public class test
    {
     public string title;
     public string name;
     public string surname;
    } 

    void  main()
    {
    List<test> t =  new List<test>();

    test t1 = new test();
    t1.title = "Mr.";
    t1.name = "John";
    t1.surname = "Doe";
    .
    .
    .
    test tn = new test();
    t.Add(t1);
    t.Add(t2);
    .
    .
    .
    .
    t.Add(tn);


    //Serialize to xml.
    try
    {
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Create))
                   {
                      XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<test>));
                      xs.Serialize(fs, t);
                   }

    }
    catch(Exception Ex)
    {
     Messagebox.Show(Ex.ToString());
    }


    //And deserialize the data from xml to objects
try
{
                      using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(szDataFile,FileMode.Open))
                      {
                         System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<test>));
                         List<test> t1 = new List<test>();
                        t1 =  xs.Deserialize(fs) as List<test>;
                      }
 }
 catch(Exception Ex)
 {
     Messagebox.Show(Ex.ToString());
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Gelatin](http://wiki.github.com/knipknap/Gelatin/) with this syntax:

```
define nl /[\r\n]/
define ws /\s+/
define fieldname /\w+/
define value /[^\r\n,]/

grammar input:
    match nl:
        do.skip()
    match fieldname ':' ws value nl:
        out.add('$0', '$3')
```